# Bash functions echo populate variable only after additional echo

Tags: bash, variables, echo

I have two bash functions, and I want to use the output of the first one inside the second one.

```sh
function get_session_name {
   ls "${FOLDER}" | grep "$1" | head -n 1 
 }
  
 function get_session { 
   local sess_name=$(get_session_name "$1" | tr -d '\n')
   # echo "${sess_name}"  <- weird behaviour line
   cat "${FOLDER}/${sess_name}"
 }
```

Now something weird happens, when it gets to
`cat "${FOLDER}/${sess_name}"` the script outputs an error message basically saying I'm trying to `cat` a folder, since `${sess_name}` is empty.

But if I uncomment the highlighted line with the `echo "${sess_name}"` before the `cat` command, then it works (and of course in the function output I also get the single echo).

How is this possible?
I'm losing it

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should use glob expressions instead of trying to parse output of `ls`. And command substitution implicitly removes trailing newlines so the `tr` does nothing useful at all

Comment: Also, you're using function declaration syntax from legacy (1980s) ksh. The modern syntax is `get_session_name() {` with no `function`.

Comment: I appreciate both your inputs, so thank you very much! I'll adapt my code, in meantime I hope somebody who solved this problem writes also.
Thank you @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: Show the *exact* error message; you may be summarizing it inaccurately.

Comment: Could you amend your question to a [mre] we can run without changes to see the same problem? An ideal test case would _create_ a temporary directory (`FOLDER=$(mktemp -d)` may suffice for the purpose), create a matching file within it, and then call your top-level function with an argument expected to match that file, thereafter providing both actual and expected output.

Comment: Also, have you run your code with xtrace enabled? (`set -x` enables trace-level logging; if your variables contain unexpected values, those logs often make the details visible). Showing not just the output of `echo "${sess_name}"`, but also how `set -x` _logs_ that line may be useful and relevant.